# Magento: Show messages inside the content area in checkout page

Tags: magento, php

I have a problem showing error messages in the content section of the checkout page. 
I want to load the messages directly from the checkout/cart.phtml page instead of page/1column.phtml so that I can put it directly near the checkout options

this is the code in my checkout/cart.phtml

```
<div class="cart-collaterals">
    <div class="col2-set">
        <div class="col-1">
                <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('crosssell') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('checkout.cart.extra') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>
            <?php if (!$this->getIsVirtual()): echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping'); endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Using this I can display how I want the success text (such as "Your product has been added to the cart") but when I have an error that tells me that I have to change quantities in the cart it doesn't load the template from checkout/cart.phtml but from page/1column.phtml

```
  <div class="main">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
            <div class="col-main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>             
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>                
            </div>
        </div>
```

What I need to do is to load the `<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>` directly from checkout/cart.phtml

Comment: And what have you tried so far? What's your code on the checkout page where the errors are caught?

Comment: I've tried changing the local.xml file but it didn't work. I'll edit the main comment and put there the code from my checkout page.